# How do I change from English to my native language in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ui, language

My whole system is in my preferred language, except Xcode. There's no use Googling *"Xcode change language"* or even *"xcode change language -iphone -IDL -parse -Python -app -localization -internationalization -swift -objective-c"*, it only turns up developer questions.

How do I change the UI language for Xcode?

Comment: XCode might not be available for every language. What is your prefered language ? (Is it somehow exotic ?)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I don't know, is Swedish exotic? :) Doesn't anyone have their Xcode in another language? Spanish, French, Japanese?

Comment: Look at the entry for Xcode in the app store.  It says English only.

Comment: It's only English. Look inside `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/`. There's only `English.lproj` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom pointed out, XCode is only available in english on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) !

If you look on other apps you'll see the available localizations for example on [Apple's Number](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825?mt=12).